# Weird Override and implementation

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I am currently programming an android app, but I have a problem.
I want to use GreenDroid for my project but while compiling the compliler give me an error : 
The return type is incompatible with Activity.getActionBar(). To my mind, the problem is from the extension and the implementation. Because I saw that :

```
public class GDActivity extends Activity implements ActionBarActivity
```

and Activity has a method getActionBar() which returns android.app.ActionBar. But the interface ActionBarActivity has getActionBar() which returns greendroid.widget.ActionBar

Can someone help me to solve this collision ?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: This is off topic for Programmers and will be migrated.

Comment: uh why not just extend ActionBarActivity and leave the Activity part?

Comment: @Smashing OPs question is about the [implementation of `GDActivity`](http://www.javased.com/?source_dir=GreenDroidQABar/src/greendroid/app/GDActivity.java) of the [Greendroid library](http://greendroid.cyrilmottier.com/reference/packages.html).

Comment: I've just refactored the getActionBar to getActionBar2 and it works fine